# Static sub-fields in mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I was reading this [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) on Angular.js, which I am trying to implement on Ruby on Rails with Mongoid, for educational purposes.

In this tutorial, data is stored in `.json` files, following this format (just part of it, for the picture):

```
{
    "additionalFeatures": "MOTOBLUR-enabled; battery manager; seven home screens; customize by moving or resizing widgets; Android HTML WebKit w/Flash Lite; BACKTRACK\u2122 navigation pad behind screen", 
    "android": {
        "os": "Android 2.1", 
        "ui": "MOTOBLUR"
    }, 
    "availability": [
        "T-Mobile,", 
        "Telus"
    ], 
    "battery": {
        "standbyTime": "267 hours", 
        "talkTime": "5 hours", 
        "type": "Lithium Ion (Li-Ion) (1170 mAH)"
    },
```

My question is the following:

I know I can make another model for the "android" key (and so on), which consists of a hash of two fields, "os" and "ui". These fields are always the same. However, I think this is a bit of overkill. I suppose adding them in the master model (let's call it "Phone") would be more efficient, ie avoiding the use of embedded_in, embeds_one relation to other model.

Is there a way to implement a `embeds_one` or `embeds_many` functionality without using other models?

Something like (not correct, but to point out):

```
field :additionalFeatures, type: String
field :android do
    field :os, type: String
    field :ui, type: String
end
```

Comment: Apparently I will have to delete this question soon. It seems the only way to have it functional is to have embedded models. Unless something radical happens, this question will be deleted later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `Hash` as field type:

```
field :android, type: Hash, :default => {os: '',ui: ''}
```

Comment: Ok, I've seen that, but how do I define the fields in the hash? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's a good way of mapping it. But as it seems, If I want to validate against that, it offers no functionality. Apparently, I DO-DO have to use embedded models.

Comment: I accept this because it's the closest thing to an answer. When combined with strong params gives the functionality I need.